# how to tell when no more progress can be made on an SSL connection

Tags: openssl, nonblocking

Here

http://marc.info/?l=openssl-users&m=124386218929227

It states that

"...This is why it is very important to understand that any possible forward progress on any port (and a write operation that returns WANT_READ may have made forward progress!) requires you to retry all pending operations on all ports...."

So am I correct in understanding that an `SSL_read()` that returned `WANT_READ` may have made forward progress (even if it did not return any data)?

I have an event driven single threaded app that has 3 non blocking ssl sockets. When each socket completes its connection, I have the sockets read until I get a `WANT_READ`. My understanding is that a `WANT_READ` means I may now invoke `select()` and wait until the socket is ready for reading again.

When `select()` returns, a loop goes through the 3 sockets calling `ssl_read()` on each of them.

Say a read on Socket 1 returned `WANT_READ` and no data.
Is it possible that Socket 2 returns some data, returns `WANT_READ` when there is nothing more to read, and has now made some progress so a read on socket 1 may now return data? But as the loop has already done the read for socket 1, it will not happen.

As the loop has run through the 3 sockets, it waits there and hangs. Could this situation happen?

If this is the case, how do I see if no more progress can be made on all 3 sockets?
For example, say the loop runs through;

- socket 1 returns `WANT_READ`.
- socket 2 returns some data, then `WANT_READ` (and makes progress such that socket 1 can now return data)
- socket 3 returns `WANT_READ`.

But based on the quote above (where any forward progress requires retrying all pending operations), I should retry all sockets again; so the second run through the loop;

- socket 1 now returns data, then `WANT_READ`
- socket 2 returns `WANT_READ`
- socket 3 now returns data (because the read on socket 1 made enough progress for socket 3 to return data), then `WANT_READ`.

But what if the last read on socket 3 made progress so socket 2 now returns data again? So my question is (if my understanding is correct), how can I tell if no more progress can be made?

**edit 1:**

So what I'm seeing is this:

My loop runs through all sockets (eg say there are 2 sockets) connected to client1

- socket 1: `ssl_read()` returns WANT_READ
- socket 2: `ssl_read()` returns data, `ssl_read()` returns data again, then `ssl_read()` finally returns WANT_READ

Then as all sockets have returned WANT_READ, I wait on `select()`. However my app is still waiting for data that the client has *already sent*. If I get the client to start another connection (while keeping the originals active), select returns and this is what I see:

- socket 1: `ssl_read()` returns data, then `ssl_read()` again returns WANT_READ
- socket 2: `ssl_read()` returns WANT_READ
- socket 3(new): `ssl_read()` returns data, then returns WANT_READ.

So select detects the new connection and runs through my loop, which goes through all active connections. This time, it has found data from socket 1 from last time, in addition to the new data on socket 3. So my theory is that select() doesn't return the first time because the data I'm waiting to receive on socket 1 has already arrived and is ready and waiting for me to call ssl_read(). But last time I called ssl_read, I got WANT_READ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `SSL_read()` returns a negative value, you should obtain the error code from `SSL_get_error()`. If the error code is **SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ** it means that you should wait (e.g. using `select()` or `poll`) for that socket to be readable (untill some data arrives from the network). When it happens you should retry SSL_read() **on that socket** again. **You don't have to** retry `SSL_read()` on all SSL sockets that you have, only on those ones that returned **SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ**. You should do simmilar things with `SSL_write()` (when it returns `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE`).

Be careful though, `SSL_read()` can potentially return (`SSL_get_error()` that is) `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE` and `SSL_write()` can return `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ`. It may happen, because SSL needs to send/receive some additional messages besides your data (e.g. in order to send your data it needs to send some message and receive response first).

To summarize:

1. When `n = SSL_read()` returns:

   a)`n > 0` --> you have just received `n` bytes of data

   b)`n < 0` --> `err = SSL_get_error()` returned

   - SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ --> `select()` untill socket is readable and call `SSL_read()` again
   - SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE --> `select()` untill socket is writable and call `SSL_read()` again

   c)`n = 0` --> `if(SSL_get_shutdown(SSL*) & SSL_RECEIVED_SHUTDOWN)` : the other side did clean shutdown, otherwise the shudown was not clean, but the SSL connection is closed you can close the socket (SSL* object too)
2. When `n = SSL_write()` returns:

   a)`n > 0` --> you have just sent `n` bytes of data

   b)`n < 0` --> `err = SSL_get_error()` returned

   - SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ --> `select()` untill socket is readable and call `SSL_write()` again
   - SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE --> `select()` untill socket is writable and call `SSL_write` again

   c)`n = 0` --> `if((err = SSL_get_error(SSL*,err)) == SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN)` : the other side did clean shutdown, otherwise the shudown was not clean, but the SSL connection is closed you can close the socket (SSL* object too)

I hope that helps.

Comment: hhmm, that was my understanding too. I've added what I'm seeing to the bottom of my question

Comment: Why do you wait untill all sockets returned SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ ? That does not make any sense. You can wait for different reasons (for each socket) at one select/poll call, then based on the results of the select call (one call for all sockets) you can do appropriate things for each socket individually

Comment: The only reason I check all sockets is because of that quote from the mailing list; when progress is made one one socket, all pending operations should be retried. It doesn't make sense, but that is how openssl works according to the mailing list post.
That issue aside, do you know why select would be hanging when there is data available to be read?

Comment: Hi
You are actually correct, turns out I wasn't including all sockets in select (doh!). I have tested whether all sockets need to be retried, and it appears this does NOT need to happen as you correctly described.
Thanks! ps as this issue is resolved, do I mark your answer as the answer, even though strictly speaking it wasn't the cause of the problem?

Comment: @AG All pending operations *on that socket* should be retried. Other sockets have nothing to do with it.