# How to read more than 16'384 bytes of data using OpenSSL?

Tags: c++, sockets, ssl, openssl

I am trying to write a HTTPS web server in C++ using the OpenSSL library.

I started from the [Simple TLS Server example](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Simple_TLS_Server) on OpenSSL's website and I came up to a point where I am unable to figure out how to read more than 16'384 bytes of data.

All the code is the same as in the Simple TLS Server example, here's the part where I read the data:

```cpp
if (SSL_accept(ssl) <= 0) {
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
} else {
    while (true) {
        char buffer[16'384];
        const auto bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buffer, 16'384);

        const auto ssl_error = SSL_get_error(ssl, bytes);
        const auto pending = SSL_pending(ssl);

        std::cout << bytes << std::endl; // This is always 16'384 when the requests exceeds 16 kB
        std::cout << ssl_error << std::endl; // This is always 0 (SSL_ERROR_NONE)
        std::cout << pending << std::endl; // This is always 0 since we read a full record of data and there's no more pending data in the record
        // How to know if there is more data to read?

        if (ssl_error == SSL_ERROR_NONE && pending == 0) {
            // This condition will always be true (see previous comments)
            break;
        }
    }

    const auto response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 12\r\n\r\nHello World!";
    SSL_write(ssl, response, strlen(response));
}
```

I am making requests using Postman or Firefox to test this, in both cases, the condition to exit the loop is true, even if the request exceeds 16kB or not.

After reading a full record, I want to know if there's another record to read the rest of the request using a loop.

As the comments in my code imply, I've done some research:

- Especially [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14393040/8445676) which explains with details how to properly read the request, which I've seen in an [other official example](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/d6e4056805f54bb1a0ef41fa3a6a35b70c94edba/apps/s_server.c#L2852).
- I've also tried making the socket async, but SSL_read seems to stay in sync.
- I've came across [this example](https://github.com/darrenjs/openssl_examples) which seems to be a quite simple usage of BIOs, but I haven't managed to get it to work either.
- Of course, I've also seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69079419/how-i-can-read-more-than-16384-bytes-using-openssl-tls) which put me in the direction of why I cannot read more than 16 kB, but with no real solution to the problem.

Is using BIO the way to go? if so, how? I don't really understand BIOs.
Or is there a solution without the use of BIO?

Comment: What problem do you wann to solve with a larger buffer? TCP is a stream protocol. Whatever size of data is put in on one side does not need to be available at the other side at once. There is no guarantee that remaining data is available immediately. Using this as an indicator that you received everything is bad idea.

Comment: From [doc](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/SSL_pending.html), `SSL_pending` is the remaining **buffered** data.

Comment: "Of course, I've also seen this post" the solution is mentioned: read from the stream again.

Comment: I can read from the stream again, but if there's no more data available, it just hangs forever.

Comment: You cannot rely on receiving all data in one go. Some packets may take longer. You must find another way to determine when to stop.

Comment: Use non blocking read?

Comment: If there’s no more data available  forever, you shouldn’t be doing the read. You should only read as much data as is specified in the content-length header. Changing the maximum read size won’t solve that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SSL_pending` only returns the number of data **inside the SSL object** which are available for immediate read. It says nothing about data still in incompletely received TLS records (which need more data for decryption) nor data buffered in the OS socket buffer nor data still in transit nor data not yet transmitted by the sender.

Thus, you cannot rely on `SSL_pending` as the condition to detect end of data and to exit the loop. Instead call `SSL_read` again. Only if this returns equal or less than 0 then there is no more to read inside the SSL session (with non-blocking sockets you have to check for temporary errors first). Note that you cannot get multiple "messages" inside a TCP/TLS connection this way since there is no message semantic there - it is only a byte stream. To distinguish between multiple messages you need to implement a message semantic on top of the byte stream.

Specifically in your case of HTTP/HTTPS the client will not close/shutdown the connection after it is done sending the request. It will just stop sending because it expects the response. In this case `SSL_read` will simply block since the connection is still open but no new data arrive. Because of this a web server actually needs to parse what is received according to the HTTP specification to determine when the request is finished (i.e. implement message semantics on top of the byte stream) - and then exit the loop even if the connection is not closed. This is not specific to HTTPS but is the same with plain HTTP, only that this would use `recv` instead of `SSL_read`.

Comment: I guess you could do something horrible and create a messaging protocol that relies on TLS records (the `SSL_pending` call simply shows how much data is left within the records), but please let's not go that way. If you do then DTLS over UDP would be more appropriate.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: correct, contrary to TCP `send` and `recv` each `SSL_write` can be matched by exactly one max size `SSL_read` since they both operate on full SSL records. Of course, one is limited by the size of the SSL record this way which is max 16k - but can be explicitly limited to less by use of record_size_limit extension. But as you said, it is not a good idea to rely on this to implement a message semantic since it was not designed for this but instead is just an implementation artifact.

Comment: Hmm, I voted this up, but if you just keep sending `SSL_read` won't it just block? There is  a new comment below the question which makes more sense.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: Of course it will block. You have to actually interpret what you've received according to the HTTP protocol to determine when the end of the request is received. This is no different from plain TCP. Made this clear in the answer.

Comment: I think I see how to do it now, thanks for the explanation!